# auto-refresh on incoming feed in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I wrote a simple "single-view" app, in which I load a webpage in UIWebView.

If I am not doing something wrong, UIWebView does not by default auto-updates itself upon url data change. For example, if a new mail arrives in gmail or a new post on Facebook wall does not seem to cause my UIWebView page refresh automatically.

Am I missing something here? And if UIWebView does not auto-refresh by default, is there a way work around this pitfall?

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to set a timer with set time intervals to refresh the web view. I have had it done with a uibutton that once pressed it will refresh the web view every so many seconds that is set to. Something like the following:

For UIButton

```
 - (IBAction)SendGPSData:(id)sender 
 {
  [webView reload];

 }
```

and for NSTimer

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(WebViewLoad:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

 -(void)WebViewLoad:(NSTimer *)theTimer
 {
 [webView reload];
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this work around. This sort of answers my question negatively, if UIWebView auto refreshes on push-data.

I thought of your solution before, but did not wish to apply just then. For I think it is annoying to make the page reload, if there is no update. I wanted to check if one could either fetch out last-update time (like ls -ltr command in unix/linux) or reload the page in background and compare the two pages if different (similar to diff command in unix) and upload only if found new.

May be I should post a new question for this.